# How to approximate the expression to $\sum x_i$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, approximation, calculus, approximate-inference

How to approximate the expression on the left hand side to $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ as $n\to \infty$

$$ \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2}{n-2\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i}{N}}
  \left(\sqrt{1+\frac{Nn\left(n-2\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i}{N}\right)}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i^2}}-1\right)\approx \sum\limits_{i=1}^{N}x_i$$

I have tried to use the result $\sqrt{1+y} \approx (1+\frac{y}{2})$
but I got ($Nn/2$)

Comment: This is not generally true without making assumptions that limit the rate of growth of the $x_i.$  Please tell us what those assumptions might be.

Comment: The maximum of $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i$ equals to $\frac{Nn}{2}$

Comment: Are you perhaps also assuming all the $x_i$ are nonnegative?

Comment: Yes that is right, all the $x_i$ are nonnegative.